# weird line draw behaviour when trying to change line thickness in Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I have placed a class extended from View in activity_main.xml and I want to draw a boarder around it. So I store the coordinates in an array and call the line drawing functions as shown below:

```
private void initView(Context ctx) {
    if(!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
        linePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        // linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(cachedBitmap == null) {
        // cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
        // cachedBitmap.setHasAlpha(false);
        // cachedBitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
        cachedCanvas = new Canvas(cachedBitmap);
    }

    COORDS[0][0] = 0.0f;    // Left-Top
    COORDS[0][1] = 0.0f;

    COORDS[1][0] = 0.0f;    // Left-Bottom
    COORDS[1][2] = getHeight();

    COORDS[2][0] = getWidth();  // Right-Bottom
    COORDS[2][3] = getHeight();
    Log.d("MYLOG", "(2,0)="+Float.toString(COORDS[2][0])+"   "+"(2,1)="+Float.toString(COORDS[2][4]) );

    COORDS[3][0] = getWidth();  // Right-Top
    COORDS[3][5] = 0.0f;

    ///*
    // drawLine(COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][6], COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][7], linePaint);
    // drawLine(COORDS[0][0]+5.0f, COORDS[0][8]+5.0f, COORDS[1][0]+5.0f, COORDS[1][9]+5.0f, linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][10], COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][11], linePaint);
    cachedCanvas.drawLine(COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][12], COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][13], linePaint);


    // */

     /*
    canvas.drawLine(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f, linePaint);
    cachedCanvas.drawLine(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, linePaint);
    // */

    canvas.drawLine(COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][14], COORDS[2][0], COORDS[2][15], linePaint);
    cachedCanvas.drawLine(COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][16], COORDS[2][0], COORDS[2][17], linePaint);

    canvas.drawLine(COORDS[2][0], COORDS[2][18], COORDS[3][0], COORDS[3][19], linePaint);
    cachedCanvas.drawLine(COORDS[2][0], COORDS[2][20], COORDS[3][0], COORDS[3][21], linePaint);

    canvas.drawLine(COORDS[3][0], COORDS[3][22], COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][23], linePaint);
    cachedCanvas.drawLine(COORDS[3][0], COORDS[3][24], COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][25], linePaint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(cachedBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);  // Set position of bitmap within the canvas
}
```

This gives me the following output

[image]

even though getWidth() and getHeight() are returning the correct values.

Anyway, I thought of making the line a bit thicker to make the output look more clear, so I 
uncommented the line `// linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);` in the above code, but now the output looks like this:
[image]

1. Why is it behaving this way?
2. How do I change the thickness of the line?

--_EDIT---

This is how the  view isdeclared in activity_main:

```
   <com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphBoarder
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

---EDIT 2---
With `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"`
[image]

Comment: What exactly does COORDS hold? If it holds coordinates, how do you store? As (x,y) pairs?

Comment: COORDS[0][0] is top-left x coordinate, COORDS[0][1] is top-left y coordinate and so on. It is mentioned in the comments inside onDraw() function

Comment: Yes, but then you have values such as `COORDS[0][10]` and `COORDS[3][24]`. What exactly do they represent?

Comment: how did that happen?? There must have been some error when posting this question, I will fix it.

Comment: I am not sure if you made this mistake while posting the question: `canvas.drawLine(COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][1], COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][1], linePaint);` should be `canvas.drawLine(COORDS[0][0], COORDS[0][1], COORDS[1][0], COORDS[1][2], linePaint);` Same for the next line.

Comment: It can't be that; COORDS is declared as `private static final float[][] COORDS = new float[4][2];` as a member field of the class; so there is no COORDS[1][2]

Comment: Oh wait, should the coordinates for left-bottom be COORDS[1][0] and COORDS[1][1]? Your code says something different.

Comment: Oh Sorry I didn't notice that. I will fix it

Comment: Edited again. SE did that to my code when I pressed the <code> button multiple times, for some reason

Comment: Anyway I think I have figured out the problem: getWidth() and getHeight() are returning results that are just 1 pixel more than the size of the canvas, and so in the first case they are being drawn just outside the canvas. They are visible in the second case (with `// linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);` uncommented) because this function is increasing the thickness of the line and so the increased thickness is appearing in the canvas. So now the queston is , why are getWidth() and getHeight() returning values in this manner?

Comment: Ok, no problem. Can give this a try: comment out `canvas.drawBitmap(cachedBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);` and `linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);`. Do you still see just two lines(as in the first picture)?

Comment: It's still incomplete :(

Comment: Added some more information to my question

Comment: One question: even though I declare the size of the view as 100dp by 100 dp in the activity_main.xml, why does getHeight() and getWidth() return 133?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought was happening, hence the test. Anyways, the real question is: Why are you seeing the lines at all. You can drawing the Bitmap at the same starting coordinates(0,0). Try replacing `getHeight()` with `cachedBitmap.getHeight()`. Same for `getWidth()`.

Comment: `One question: even though I declare the size of the view as 100dp by 100 dp in the activity_main.xml, why does getHeight() and getWidth() return 133?`: `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` return dimensions in pixels. `100 density-pixels` != `100 pixels`(unless screen density = 1).

Comment: It still just gives the two lines

Comment: These two lines are the problem: `android:layout_width="100dp"` and `android:layout_height="100dp"`. Set both to `wrap_content`.

Comment: so how do I set all my measurements in pixels then? That is, set distances in pixels in the xml file, as well as do my calculations in pixels in the java program?

Comment: chat says I'm not logged in, and when I try to log in it says `Oops! Something Bad Happened!` with a picture of some cat on a laptop

Comment: this has been problem for me since a long time I've never been able to go into stackoverflow chat. I can go into other SE site chat rooms but never this one